# What should I do to get the best internet possible?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

for some time now I've been thinking of how I can get the best internet on my room, as it is pretty far away from my router. I can't take one long ethernet cable either as it's two doors in the way. I was also thinking about using a powerline adapter, but my room also has its own fuse box so that might not work.

So what should I do to get internet in there? I'm using my computer for gaming, so a wired solution is best. I will link a rough (and bad) sketch of my apartment below.

[image: apartment sketch]

Comment: Wireless bridge to boost the WiFi signal?

Comment: It's cool that you're thinking about it but without any kind of dimensions on that graphic it's hard to judge the actual distance. It doesn't really look that far, though for wireless walls with (a lot) of metal in them might be problematic. Depending on your doors you might also be able to run a cable just under them, though it's probably not going to look really neat.

Answer (score 0):

Acquire flat Cat6 cable, such as [https://www.amazon.com/Cat-Ethernet-Cable-White-Connectors/dp/B00WD017GQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WD017GQ) or https://www.vpi.us/sf-patch-cables/cable-sf-cat6-811#/boot_style-standard/length-50_ft which will allow you to run it between the door and door frame, or between door and floor.